# While in development in Xpages Libraries, changes are not picked up

Tags: java, xpages

I work with multiple XPages Libraries that contain all of our Java code outside Domino Designer. I'm using Eclipse Mars and have setup the Xpages SDK to make this work. Most of the Java code is called from Xpages (or managed bean inside a nsf). But everytime when I make a change in our Java code, the change is not picked up. I need to "restart task http" on my Domino development server everytime.

When I turn on debugging and change Java code, all changes are picked up immediately but it will crash my server when I change a return type or add a new function or move classes between packages.

Is there an easier way to develop in Java without restarting the HTTP task everytime I make change (or prevent those server crashes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging from Eclipse, if you use the Stop option, it crashes the server. If you use Continue, it works fine.

In terms of hot-swapping code, there isn't a way currently. JRebel can be used with some servers, but I don't know of anyone who has got it working with Domino.

It's not specific to plugins though. The same is true of any shared Java code, presumably because it's compiled to byte code and cached. See this blog post where I had issues with SCXD http://www.intec.co.uk/single-copy-xpage-design-some-learning-and-why-its-not-for-me/. There are various `tell http osgi` commands including ones for bundles etc, but I haven't found one that successfully reload plugins. I think Cameron Gregor did some investigations as well, but also couldn't find a way. It's one of the issues I highlighted with OSGi development on Domino on my blog http://www.intec.co.uk/from-xpages-to-web-app-part-seven-osgi-application-development-introduction/.

Comment: I never used to have a problem with crashing during debugging until IBM did all their JVM upgrades and hotfixes. I used to be able to hot-swap the code with no crash. Even small one line changes within a method can cause a crash, it does not seem to be predictable what causes the crash as such I have given up on trying to use the hot-swap functionality.

Comment: There is no simple way using OSGi to pick up your changes without restarting. You can 'refresh' the bundle just fine, however due to the way the XspLibrary system is designed, it will never release it's hold on the classloader that it received from the originally loaded bundle.
Alternative ideas are, Seeing if JRebel works as Paul has said.
Otherwise if your application architecture supports the notion of using OSGi's service layer architecture, you could redesign your bundles to be services, which support the notion of start/stop/refresh better as there is less classloading between bundles

Comment: Jrebel looks great. I'm thinking of trying it out. Thank you for the comments and answers.

Comment: Cameron posted a blog today showing how he got JRebel working for Domino. Sounds like it's worth checking out.

Comment: I just wanted to let anyone know that we use JRebel and that it works. You will need 9.0.1 FP4 at least (if you need also 'debugging' that doesn't crash) and you will have to also add the "-Drebel.base=xxxx" in your JrebelInfoFile.txt if you start the Domino server as a service.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg I am trying to get JRebel running on a domino server 9.0.1 FP9 but without any success. When I start the domino server - configured for JRebel - I always get the following console error message: `java.io.IOException: WaitForMultipleObjects`